# Allowing user to hide columns when sheet is locked

Tags: excel, vba, show-hide

I am using the following VBA script to provide users certain permissions when a sheet in a workbook is locked. I cannot figure out how to add a line that would also allow the user to hide and unhide columns. Any suggestions?

```
Sub EnableOutlining()
'Update 20140603
Dim xWs As Worksheet
Set xWs = Application.ActiveSheet
Dim xPws As String
xPws = Application.InputBox("Password:", xTitleId, "", Type:=2)
xWs.Protect Password:=xPws, Userinterfaceonly:=True
xWs.EnableOutlining = True
xWs.EnableOutlining = True
xWs.EnableAutoFilter = True
xWs.EnableFormatConditionsCalculation = True
End Sub
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Going to work on a way to check that last user action was in fact hide / unhide and nothing else. But for now should allow user to hide / unhide.

For columns:

```
xWs.protect Password:= "1234",AllowFormattingColumns:= true
```

For rows:

```
xWs.protect Password:= "1234",AllowFormattingRows:= true
```

This script should help limit user activity to only adjusting column widths. (lastAction describes hiding columns as adjust width, must be that hiding columns is really just a function that minimizes column width, not some special action)

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim lastAction As String
        lastAction = Application.CommandBars("Standard").Controls("&Undo").List(1)

    If lastAction <> "Column Width" Then
        Application.EnableEvents = False
        Application.Undo
        MsgBox "PLEASE ONLY HIDE OR UNHIDE COLUMNS"
        Application.EnableEvents = True
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks but I'm not quite following what you are trying to do. I just want enable a user to hide or unhide a column of their choosing in a locked workbook using VBA. There isn't a need to specify columns values in other worksheets.  To the first part of your response in suggesting to use "xWs.AllowFormattingColumns:= true," I get an error saying that "Method or data member not found." I think this is because AllowFormattingColumns isn't part of the EnableOutlining() function.

Comment: danny see edit, sorry for the confusion. this will work now but it will also allow users to make other formatting changes outside of just hiding / unhiding. i am trying to come up with a way to disallow any formatting change outside of hide/unhide. @AJD I hope to fix this up tonight, ty for help& input.

Answer (score 0):

To do this you just need to change the sections your allowing users to work on when locking the sheet. I selected everything but "select locked cells" and it would then work. This meant the code was still hidden in cells I didn't want to be edited but the hide expand button based on my VBA code was working.

Comment: Your answer needs some supporting information. Can you try to be a bit more explicit and maybe share some code of how exactly to do what you're suggesting?